# Featuretools categorical handling

Tags: python, pandas, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, featuretools

Featuretools offers integrated functionality to handle categorical variables

> ```
> variable_types={"product_id": ft.variable_types.Categorical} https://docs.featuretools.com/loading_data/using_entitysets.html
> ```

However should these be `strings` or `pandas.Category` types for optimal compatibility with Featuretools?

## edit

Also, is it required to manually specify all columns like in
https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-appointment-noshow/blob/master/Tutorial.ipynb or will they be inferred automatically from fitting pandas datatypes

```
import featuretools.variable_types as vtypes
variable_types = {'gender': vtypes.Categorical,
                  'patient_id': vtypes.Categorical,
                  'age': vtypes.Ordinal,
                  'scholarship': vtypes.Boolean,
                  'hypertension': vtypes.Boolean,
                  'diabetes': vtypes.Boolean,
                  'alcoholism': vtypes.Boolean,
                  'handicap': vtypes.Boolean,
                  'no_show': vtypes.Boolean,
                  'sms_received': vtypes.Boolean}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Pandas Category dtype when loading your data into Featuretools. This will save you significantly on memory usage compared to using strings.

You are not required to manually specify each variable type when loading your data. Featuretools will attempt to infer it from the Pandas dtype if not provided.